# Predicted vs Actual values of GBM in H2O

Tags: r, h2o, predict

I am trying to calculate Gini for my regression models and since there is no Gini index for regression models, I am getting all the scores and calculate it using Gini functions in R using this code:

```
preds <-h2o.predict(model, test)
pred_vs_actual <- as.data.frame(h2o.cbind(test$target,preds)
```

Does this code return the correct pair values for actual and predictions? I know that there is no order in a spark table but I am not sure if this is also the case for H2O object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes what you have (`pred_vs_actual`) will cbind your model's predictions with the corresponding row (record). As a quick check, when you look at the first few rows of `pred_vs_actual` you should be able to verify that the cbind does what you expect.